# Падает скорость интернета

Tags: провайдер

Бывает, что смотрю спокойно фильм онлайн, как вдруг скорость падает в десятки раз и страницы начинают открываться очень долго, а видео подавно не грузится. Но ранее это лечилось тем что после переподключения модема - всё становилось нормально на некоторое время. Я то думал провайдер, но сейчас мне уже перестало помогать переподключение модема, и я попробовал отключить свой антивирус NOD32 и сразу скорость нормализовалась. Я сделал вывод что это из-за него, почему-то иногда он убивает скорость. Скажите, как этого избежать, не меняя антивирусник? Может в hosts заблокировать какие-то сервера, чтобы nod32 не общался с ними?

Comment: Много раз сталкивался с тем что НОД32 тупо не видит вирусы! Проверял Cure-It от DrWeb, который находил то что не видел НОД32. Сейчас перешел на Kaspersky Free. И проблемы с скоростью и выловом троянов пропали :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если связь через модем тормознутая (например с использованием GPRS или 3G), то вполне возможно, что при попытке открывать дополнительный канал все начинает жутко застревать. Не исключено, что НОД захотел произвести какие-нибудь обновления базы... и "монополизировал" весь траффик.

Попробуйте проверить какие программы у вас лезут в сеть (Outpost Firwall в этом смысле хорошо показывает). Возможно проблема в них.

Comment: Добавлю, что если NOD еще и фаерволл, то он может просто проверять трафик.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

нужно отключить фаервол у NOD32

Answer (score 0):

В некоторых случаях, антивирусные программы могут сканировать входящий и исходящий трафик, что может замедлить интернет-соединение. Вы можете попробовать заблокировать определенные серверы, чтобы предотвратить связь антивируса NOD32 с ними. Для этого можно внести изменения в файл hosts на вашем компьютере. [Почитайте здесь, как увеличить скорость интернета](https://teledom.org/net/kak-uvelichit-skorost-interneta.html), там написаны дельные советы.